# how to pass the uncertain parameters form one method to another on Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

how to pass the uncertain parameters form one method to another method.both method are contain uncertain parameters！

such as:

```
- (void)test:(id)arg1,...{
    NSLog(@"invoke");
}

- (void)test2:(id)arg1,...{
    [self test:arg1,...];
}
```

but i got error!

Comment: did you just paste the same paragraph 3 times?

Comment: You can't do what you want.